# Record(s) cannot be read; no read permission on <table>

Tags: ms-access-2010

I am getting one of those warning messages which states, "Record(s) cannot be read; no read permission on ".  Here is what I've done thus far:

1. Checked the permissions and confirmed that all the relevant tables,
   forms, queries and reports are accessible by Admin (me).
2. Run Compact & Repair.
3. Deleted the table in question and re-created from scratch.

None of these has solved the problem.  In addition, I can open the table in question directly.

This particular Access database has been copied over from a template and customized for a specific clinical study.  This warning message is occurring with numerous Access databases and started appearing after we upgraded from Office 2003 to 2010.

Comment: What is the context of that error message?  Is triggered by a query?  Opening a recordset? Something else?